# What is the best practice for placing an @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a SpringBoot application, with some additional properties classes annotated with **@ConfigurationProperties**, and also, I have some config. classes annotated with **@Configuration**.

What is the best place where to place **@EnableConfigurationProperties** annotation? I saw it above the main class, but above the config. class, which is a consumer of properties class, seems like better placement and make more sense to me. What is the best practice for placing this annotation?

e.g:

```
@SpringBootApplication
//should it be here:
//@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProperties::class)
class MyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}

    

@Configuration
//or here?
//@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProperties::class)
class MyConfig(
    private val props: MyConfigProperties
){

    // some methods, that uses props
}



@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("props")
data class MyConfigProperties(val myProp: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you should put the annotation in the Configuration class that uses those properties.

Comment: Thanks, do you have some reason for that, or just because it's usually placed there?

Comment: Because in configuration classes you also declare beans which might use these properties or which are relevant for a certain package if you are using DDD, for example. Furthermore, the main class should be kept clean with annotations that have a global purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Those annotations have different purposes.

`@ConfigurationProperties` is letting developer maps the entire `.properties` and `.yml` file into an object easily.

`@Configuration` indicates that the class can be used by the Spring IoC container as a source of bean definitions.

One big advantage of `@ConfigurationProperties`can be `Externalized Configuration`

Documentation says:

> Spring Boot lets you externalize your configuration so that you can
> work with the same application code in different environments. You can
> use properties files, YAML files, environment variables, and
> command-line arguments to externalize configuration. Property values
> can be injected directly into your beans by using the @Value
> annotation, accessed through Spring’s Environment abstraction, or be
> bound to structured objects through @ConfigurationProperties.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not answer for my question. My question is, which class should be annotated with `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProps)` annotation.